# How to pass params to function in useQuery of react query when enabled is set to false?

Tags: reactjs, axios, react-query

I am creating a query that allows me to duplicate a template. The query that duplicate's the templates needs an id, but initially does not have any id. How can I pass id as params to the query function when I call it on an onClick function.

Function to duplicate template:

```
duplicate: ({ queryKey: [_key, id] }) => axios.get(`${base_url}templates/${id}/duplicate?auth_token=${auth_token}`),
```

My Query:

```
 const { data: duplicateTemplate, refetch: duplicateTemplateFunc } = useQuery(
    [`template],
      api.duplicate,
    {
      enabled: false,
      onSuccess: () => {
        message.success('Template successfully duplicated.')
      },
    }
  )
```

The onClick method is used in render method of antd table, which gives me the id through `record.id`

```
 render: (_value, record) => (
    <div onClick={() => duplicateTemplateFunc(record.id)>
        Duplicate
    </div>
 ),
```

Comment: are you sure that `duplicateTemplate` is a query? It sound a lot like a mutation to me...

Comment: yup, it's a get request, I am not posting anything, I solved it using try catch for now

Comment: mutations are not defined by the http method (get or post), but by the question of if they have a side-effect on the server. sure, there shouldn't be GET requests with side-effects, but I've seen the weirdest APIs. `duplicateTemplate` sounds like it takes a template and makes a copy of it and stores that somewhere (in the database?) and if that's the case, it should be a mutation..

Comment: Oh, okay, thanks. I will try and use it as a mutation.

Answer (score 0):

```
When using the useQuery hook from the react-query library and setting 
enabled to false, you can still pass parameters to the function that is 
being 
executed. You just need to pass the parameters as an object to the second 
argument of the useQuery hook.
const { data, isLoading, error } = useQuery(
["fetchData", { id: 123, name: "John" }],
(_key, params) => {
return fetch(`https://your-api.com/data/${params.id}?name=${params.name}`)
  .then(res => res.json());
},
{ enabled: false }
);
```

Comment: I logged id in onClick and id was returned, but when I logged id in the useQuery function it returned undefined.

Comment: use code snippet for code example